# Tag Cleanup: `imageprocessing` to `image-processing`

Tags: discussion, tags

To better fit the style of multi-word tags, should the current tag [imageprocessing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imageprocessing) be converted to [image-processing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)?